# How to use Web Worker in Angular 6

Tags: angular5, angular6, web-worker, worker, angular7

I want to use web worker in our project, can you give some examples of how to use web worker in angular 6 because I read some examples but it's not enough.
I try to using throw blob but I need to add some external script files in worker file and I stuck. *importScripts* function not working here.

If anyone have some reference please send me.

Comment: 1. https://medium.com/@suresh.patidar/running-web-worker-in-angular-6-application-a-step-by-step-guide-74e88c566ba4

2. https://medium.com/@damoresac/using-web-workers-on-angular-6-6fd0490d07b5

Comment: thank you @ŽarkoSelak, I already fixed this issue.